# the time difference in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have data set content many columns and date time `['%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S']`

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJSzV.png)

I'm try to find the difference between date time for all rows.
I'm try by using this code

```
df['difference_time'] = (df['timezone']-df['timezone'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

and the output

but the output not right I'm not sure where is the problem in my code

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a83t4.png)

Comment: Good work breaking the images again... Provide their content **as text**.

Comment: Please provide small sample data set (3-5 rows) and desires data set in text form (so we could use it when coding an answer for you). Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Phrases like `"the output not right"` don't help to understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Isn't it just that your subtraction is backward?  Try b-a instead of a-b.